# INNER, LEFT or RIGHT JOIN to get columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 4 tables in SQL Server 2012. This is my diagram:

[image]

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    pc.Product_ID, d.Dept_ID, c.Category_ID, sc.SubCategory_ID 
FROM 
    dbo.ProductConfiguration pc
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SubCategory sc ON sc.SubCategory_ID = pc.SubCategory_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Category c ON c.Category_ID = sc.Category_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Department d ON d.Dept_ID = c.Dept_ID
WHERE 
    pc.Product_ID = 459218
```

What is the best way, (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT) to get columns values? I need be careful with performance

Thanks a lot

Comment: They have different meanings; which one to choose depends on how the data is located and your need. Look at this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: [what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) OR [Whats the difference between inner join, left join, right join, and full join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) -- Between these two posts, you have over 2.8 million views. This question appears to be too broad or should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for all comments

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with performance.

I suppose every product belongs to a subcategory which belongs to a category which belongs to a department. So you **inner join** all the tables; this is the normal thing to do.

If one of the entities were not mandatory, but optional, say there are categories that don't belong to a department <sup>1</sup>, but you still wanted to show the row, then you'd outer join the table. You'd use a **left outer join** on departments. We never use **right outer joins**, because these are supposed to be harder to read, and they do essentially the same as left joins.

<sup>1) i.e. category.dept_id coud be null</sup>

Answer (score 0):

your query best variant is LEFT JOIN, from its do not loses your information

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you, use **execution plans** when you need to update the **performance**. using execution plan you can understand the behaviors. it will grate help for future.
Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation